# Is it correct to say that a variable is an instance of a data type?

Tags: c++, semantics

(that can change its value over the course of the program)

Or is 'instance of something' strictly related to classes and objects? If so, how would you define the concept of 'variable' when it comes to C++?

Comment: C# and Java differ from C++ in two interesting ways.  First, they attempt to unify the primitive types with the object (and struct) types (so you can talk about an instance of int), whereas C++ does not.  Second, in C# and Java, variables of object types are implicitly *references to* instances (of classes) in the heap and also that we don't talk about pointers to objects, whereas in C++, like @coredump's answer, local variables of object types are bindings to instances on the stack, and we explicitly distinguish between objects and pointers to objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, it is correct to call values of primitive types  *instances* of that type (see for example ["C++ Type System"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279663.aspx), from Visual Studio's manual, but I am still looking for another source), though I believe this term is mostly used when discussing objects.
An object is an instance of a class C if it was built from a constructor defined either in class C or one of its subclasses.

A variable in C++ is not a runtime concept. It exists inside your compiler as a lexical binding between the variable's name and an abstract (mutable if not const) location. Once a program is compiled, variables are not there anymore. Instead, data is read and written in registers, memory, etc.

Comment: "*Values of primitive types are generally not said to be instances of that type; it is reserved to objects and classes.*" That's not true at all. Nowhere in the standard are values of primitive types not considered objects. Nor does the definition of a variable change in any way depending on whether it is a user-defined class or a primitive type.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've never heard anyone refer to integers as instances of something in the context of C++, and I'm pretty sure it's correct to say they *aren't* instances of anything even if the standard doesn't explicitly mention that. If not, what are they instances of? I also don't see where this answer claims that the definition of a variable changes between primitive types and objects; it seems to be (afaik correctly) claiming that "instances" simply have nothing to do with the definition of a variable.

Comment: @Ixrec: "*If not, what are they instances of?*" The type `int`. The C++ standard does not make a distinction between primitive types and non-primitive types when talking about what variable declarations do. So `T t;` declares an object of type `T`, no matter what type `T` happens to be.

Comment: @Ixrec: Note that *literals* are a different kind of thing. Literals are a kind of prvalue. But you can't make literal variables, so that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 5):

> Or is 'instance of something' strictly related to classes and objects? If so, how would you define the concept of 'variable' when it comes to C++?

To put it as concisely as possible for C++

- A *variable* is a **name** (in code) for a *location in memory* to be determined at runtime.
- An *instance* is an **object** which *resides in memory* at runtime.

Just to be clear:

- Not all areas of memory contain objects.  For example, some areas of memory may contain 'garbage' values.
- Not all memory storing objects will have been given a name in code.   Objects may reside in un-named areas of memory such as a position in an array, or somewhere on the *Heap* referenced by a pointer.
- When an area of memory contains garbage, it's usually either because no object has been initalised at that location, or because some previously existing object has been destroyed.

Comment: PODs are objects in C++. Not all regions of memory are objects, but PODs are not just regions of memory.

Comment: I second NicolBolas: PODs are objects. However, you have a point when you talk about a newly `malloc()`'ed, but uninitialized buffer: it's a memory area that's not an object yet. Likewise, an object which has been explicitly destructed: It's a memory region that's not an object anymore.

Comment: @NicolBolas fair comment, I've changed that wording slightly

Answer (score 1):

Well, what does "correct" mean?

If we want to be super-strict about it, we need to distinguish between:

- The **syntax** side: **expressions** *have* (static) **types**
- The **semantics** side: **objects** are *instances* of **classes**

So then a variable—being an expression—would *have* a type.  Its value—the object that it refers to—would be an instance of some class.  And note that the variable's type and the object's class are not generally the same thing—the variable's static type puts an *upper bound* on the objects' runtime classes, so that the classes must be a *subtype* of the class that corresponds to the type.

Do you want to repeat that big mouthful all the time?  Heck no.  How strictly vs. loosely we want to talk depends on context.  So often there's really no problem with saying that "the variable is an instance of this type."  What's happening there really is that we're using the variable and the type metonymically to refer to the object and a superclass of its runtime class.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to spend your entire life in purism and sophism ... yes.

Every time you keep something that's uniquely identified an use to *forge* other uniquely identifiable things you are doing instantiation.

- A project instantiate into products
- A source instantiate into executables
- A template instantiate into types.
- A type instantiate into variables.

Some of those *instantiation* may have more accurate names, but in general this works.

Answer (score 0):

Many people reserve "instance" for instances of classes. If you do that then in C++, a variable could be an instance of a class, a reference to an instance, a pointer to an instance, or a primitive type (you'd likely count structs as classes in that context, they are almost completely the same). In Java or Objective-C, variables would never be instances but possibly references to instances.

Forgot: For a short time, a C++ pointer can be a pointer to raw memory, for example "this" before the constructor starts executing. You'd likely not call *this an instance yet at this point.